# Magento Disabled Products Showing on Google Search

Tags: magento2, database, magento-enterprise, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.2

Magento disabled products are showing in google search results. How can i remove them from google search result?.

When I click them, my website open and show 404 error page. Showing this error for users can be a bad user experience. I am using Magento 1.9.2. I do not want to show disabled products on google search result.

How do I remove these links from Google?

Answer (score 1):

To remove your disabled products from the Google search results you must first claim your domain on Google Search Console (previously Google Webmaster).

Once this has been done you will have a set of options to review, under the menu on the left hand side select Google Index > Remove URL's.

This will prevent you with a page to be able to 'temporarily hide' URL's from Google's search results. This will only work so long as the URL's you are trying to hide are no longer accessible and are not included within your site map if you provide one to Google.

Answer (score 0):

If the products have been deleted, this is completely normal and the correct way to tell Google and other search engines that the product is no longer available.

The links that lead to 404 messages will be crawled by Google and will slowly be removed from the index.

There is plenty of information on the web about this, I recommend you sign up for Google webmaster tools and keep an eye on any messages for your site.

> Showing this error for users can be a bad user experience.

Since these are disabled products and not available, a 404 error is better than leading to user frustration that they cannot purchase a product that is not available.

Depending on the traffic to your website, these links will be removed.

Also important, make sure that these links do not appear in your sitemap.

Comment: I have 500 to 1000 disabled products which can be enabled later. Is there any way we can hide those products on google search? because we will modify data of those products and enable them later. is there any temporary solution to hide them on google search

Comment: Disable the products and make sure they are not in your sitemap. When you are ready, enable and ensure they are in the sitemap. This process takes time.

Comment: please can you explain how can i achieve this? how can i include or exclude disable products from magneto sitemap.

Comment: if you disable the products and generate a new sitemap they should be automatically excluded.

Comment: I have generated sitemap on magento and submitted on google webmaster. All pages are indexed properly and no error found however, still showing disabled products on google search

Comment: This process is not instant, it can takes days, weeks or months depending on the popularity and traffic to your website. If when you click on the link from Google you get the desired result on your website, there is nothing more for you to do.